# How to insert euro symbol into Word document with Open TBS?

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am creating a merged word document using the Open TBS plugin for Tinybutstrong, however I cannot get it to display the euro symbol correctly when merging from a php variable.

I have tried:

1. Entering the charecter directly as '€' within my variable
2. Using the html entity name/code
3. Using auto complete in word to convert a code to the symbol

None of these display correctly, has anyone come across/been able to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP code must be saved in UTF-8 (without DOM).
Your database (if any) must store data in UTF-8.
And your TBS template must be loaded with the option `OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8`.

> $TBS->LoadTemplate('document.docx', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);